# How to write row_number() over clause in linq to Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Using Entity Framework and LINQ, I need to get row number together with an entity, e.g. for loan I have multiple invoices and I want to select specific invoice together with its sequence number.

Basically, I'd need to know how to write equivalent to this:

```
select 
    nr, i.* 
from 
    [Invoices] i 
inner join
    (select 
         row_number() over (order by IssueDate) nr, id 
     from 
         [Invoices]
     where 
         LoanId = 5) t on t.id = i.id
where 
    i.id = 207
```

Comment: If someone downvotes, please comment why. I spent quite a lot of time looking for the solution and reduced the question to minimum so it is as easy understandable as possible

Comment: IMO this does not deserve the downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/055911ff-6db6-48cb-8e50-bd6415b7eefe/rownumber-and-linq?forum=adodotnetentityframework) `ROW_NUMBER` is not supported in L2E. If you don't mind the overhead of loading all invoices for a given `LoanId` into memory, then it can be be done easily in C# with the overload of the `Select` method on `IEnumerable` that produces an index for each item, e.g.:

```
//First select the invoices
var invoices = from i in dbContext.Invoices
               where i.LoanId == 5
               order by i.IssueDate
               select i;

var indexedInvoice = invoices.ToList().Select((i, count) => new { Invoice = i, RowCount = count })
                     .First(ii => ii.Invoice.Id == 207);
```

I can see how this can be less than optimal in some situations, so you might consider bypassing L2E here and execute your query as a plain old sql string, depending on how performance-critical it is, and on how many invoices there usually are for a single loan.

Comment: Thanks, I read that answer before but it is from 2008 with additional comment from 2011. EF evolved since that time so I preferred to ask again.Loading it all into memory is really not an option for expected data amount. I can create SP or database function but it would be nice if I could keep the code in .Net at least until the data model is more stable.

Comment: @FilipHurta if the data model is not set in stone, you can also consider adding the "sequence number" to the `invoice` table (using a trigger to auto-set it on insert).